# Is there any way to know if the DatagramChannel.receive(ByteBuffer) method has discarded some data from the packet if ByteBuffer is too small?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, datagram

The docs of the method DatagramChannel.receive(ByteBuffer) states that it will read the data from the channel equal to the ByteBuffer size and discard the remaining if the Buffer size is too small to hold the data. I was wondering if there's any way to know that the receive method has discarded the data.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique is to use a buffer one larger than the largest expected datagram. Then if you get one that size, it has almost certainly been truncated, and it is also an application protocol error.

Comment: Yea the suggested size should be larger but is there a way to know that if the size of buffer is smaller than the packet and some of the packet's data has been truncated ?

Comment: No, this is the only way.